# List like parameter in django template. Is it possible?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, templates

Is there any possibility to send a list or a tuple like a parameter to this function:

self.response.out.write(template.render(self.path, sendingList))

i'm new to this and i heard that you can send only dictionary. Is it true?

Answer (score 1):

you can only pass a dict, but items in that dict can be lists:

```
self.response.out.write(template.render(self.path, {'numbers': [1,2,3,4,5,6]}))
```

which you can then access in your template with `{{ numbers}}`, and iterate over it with

```
{% for number in numbers%}{{ number}}{% endfor %}
```